# Required `<select>` input erroneously allows selection of default option

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have this very simple select. It is a required element of a form but atm it is accepting even the first option.

**Is there a simple way to say required a value that is not the first option?**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>

<form name="myForm">
    <label for="singleSelect"> Single select: </label><br>
    <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="data.singleSelect" required>
        <option value="">Please select an option</option>
        <option value="option-1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="option-2">Option 2</option>
    </select><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Apply selected true and disabled property.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.min.js"></script>


<form name="myForm">
  <label for="singleSelect"> Single select: </label><br>
  <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="data.singleSelect" required>
  <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Please select an option</option>
    <option value="option-1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option-2">Option 2</option>
  </select><br>
</form>
```

Comment: but what if the user doesnt select anything ??